# How to call a variable has do_shortcode outside to a function (Wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables, shortcode

I have a demo code likes:

```
  add_shortcode('xyz','xyz')
  $cf7 = do_shortcode('[abc]'); 
function xyz(){
    global $cf7;
    return $cf7;
    }
```

but it does not work,
I know if I put "$cf7 = do_shortcode('[abc]');" to inside function, it will work well.
But some reasons, I just want $cf7 outside. Sorry for my bad English
Thanks

Comment: First of all add semi colons  ; after add_shortcode('xyz','xyz') please.

Comment: It does not work this way, because of _variable scope_. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: do you guys have any suggestions to make that work?